# Haskell indentation in a do block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am implementing arithmetic expression tree examples from the book *Programming in Haskell* by Hutton, and I'm getting a syntax error:

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

```
firstgrm = do t <- secgrm
             ( do { symbol "##";
               o <- firstgrm;
           return (O (t ## o));}
        +++ return t )                         -- parse error here
```

Comment: The most obviously wrong syntax is the dangling semicolon, but the whole thing just looks weird. My brain doesn't work very well with the details of Haskell's layout rule, so I tend to be extremely boring about how I indent my code.

Comment: and what is that `(+++)` operator?  You may convince me that with proper spacing and a definition for that `(+++)` that this should work, but it certainly isn't idiomatic....

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this was a fine question that has received some unwarranted rude comments. I hope we do better next time.

Comment: I know it helps to understand code if people see what my intention is, but for this I was just questioning about my syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Where curly braces are omitted, Haskell uses the [off-side rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule); blocks are expressed by their indentation. The [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) has an okay description of how Haskell indentation works:

> All *grouped* expressions must be exactly aligned. On the first line, Haskell counts everything to the left of the expression as indent, even though it is not whitespace.

In your example, you have two `do` blocks. The inner one uses curly braces, and the outer one does not. You could get your code to compile by adding curly braces to the outer `do` block:

```
firstgrm = do { t <- secgrm;
             ( do { symbol "##";
               o <- firstgrm;
           return (O (t ## o));}
        +++ return t ) }
```

... though I really don't recommend it.

It is customary to *always* omit braces. The indentation rules also make it awkward to put a `do` block within parentheses, so we usually avoid that as well.

```
firstgrm = do t <- secgrm
              x t +++ return t
  where
    x t = do symbol "##"
             o <- firstgrm
             return (O (t ## o))
```